# How can I keep a Delayed_Job task from failing with "execution expired"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I thought that since it was a background process, that there wouldn't be any sort of timeout. I used delayed_job to run reports in the background. Very large, long-running reports are failing with this message.

I'm running Rails 2.3.5 on Apache2 with Phusion Passenger.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the [delayed_jobs faq wiki page on github](https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job/wiki):

```
# config/initializers/delayed_job_config.rb
Delayed::Job.destroy_failed_jobs = false
silence_warnings do
  Delayed::Job.const_set("MAX_ATTEMPTS", 3)
  Delayed::Job.const_set("MAX_RUN_TIME", 5.minutes)
end
```

You are looking to increase the MAX_RUN_TIME.  The default is 4 hours, so you likely want to set it to something like `6.hours` or longer.  It should be the *longest* you think the job should take, but this is clearly application / job specific and you likely know what the longest time that's acceptable is.

Comment: D'oh! RTFM strikes again. Thanks a lot Brett!

Comment: I do the same thing all the time, no problem. Good luck!

Comment: The gem's readme has moved, and you can read about `max_run_time` in the [gory details](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#gory-details).